# Add some labels to a tableViewCell. The tables number depend on server data

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to add some labels to a tableViewCell. The labels number may be 3 or 5 or more. The numbers depend on server data. How can I create it and use it repeatedly.

Comment: Now I create labels dynamically in cell. But I can't use these labels when I reuse cell. I have to remove all previous labels and create again.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get this done. 
1. You can use section and rows method. Add label to one cell and call it repeatedly in accordance with no. of label from server. 
2. Create labels dynamically in cell and manage height of cell in accordance with labels .

Comment: Now I create labels dynamically in cell. But I can't use these labels when I reuse cell.Now I remove all labels and create again.

Comment: Yes, for each cell you need to recreate labels and cells are reuse